# Book about linear groups

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, book-recommendation, linear-groups

Please advise a good book about linear groups, their actions (as, for example, PGl acts on projective space, etc.), as well as the relationship between themselves.
(ideally if they were considered from the point of view of Lie groups)

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2528693/is-there-good-source-on-lie-groups-with-no-knowledge-of-differential-manifolds-o).

Comment: Have you searched through this site and e.g. looked at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/190983/96384 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/832624/96384?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that books

Vinberg, Onishchik — “Lie Groups and Algebraic Groups”

Claudio Procesi — “Lie Groups, An Approach through Invariants and Representations”

are good for that purpose.